# Javascript - Place some HTML into the document

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, document

I am a Javascript beginner.

I try to have these two pieces of html placed into the markup. The anchors' IDs are set from tab-1 to tab-6.

This is what I've wrote so far. It doesn't do anything. Anybody got some ideas?

```
<script>

    if (window.location.hash == "#tab-1" || "#tab-2" || "#tab-3" || "#tab-4" || "#tab-5" || "#tab-6") {
    } else { 
      document.write("<div id="tagline"><p id="quote">"Play for fun or don't play at all!"</p> <p id="namer">- S. Pussehl</p> </div>") 
    }
```

Comment: Note: In your `if`, you need to place `window.location.hash ==` everywhere,  because `"#tab-2"` on its own is always true.

Comment: And you need to escape the `"` character inside a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code:

1. If expression. You need to separate all expressions and to check what you want.
2. You can't separate the line without symbol "+". Or everything in the same line.
3. Quotes inside quotes. Or use '""', "''", or use \' = quote

Try to use it:

```
if (window.location.hash == "#tab-1" || window.location.hash == "#tab-2"
 || window.location.hash == "#tab-3" || window.location.hash == "#tab-4" 
 || window.location.hash == "#tab-5" || window.location.hash == "#tab-6"
) {
 // Some code 
} else { document.write('<div id="tagline">' +
                            '<p id="quote">"Play for fun or dont play at all!"</p>' +
                            '<p id="namer">- S. Pussehl</p> </div>'
           ); 
    }
```

Comment: +1 for ans, but you should describe what you have changed in code and why, and  what were errors, so op can understand.

Comment: Thank You, i do need to make it reload now, but this does work!!

Answer (score 0):

you are wrapping your HTML with double quote and giving `id` to your elements with double quote so it won't work.

You should learn string concatenation in JavaScript.

And your JavaScript should like below.

```
document.write('<div id="tagline"> <p id="quote">"Play for fun or don\'t play at all!"</p> <p id="namer">- S. Pussehl</p> </div>');
```

UPDATE : 
And in your if condition you should compare `window.location.hash` with all, individually.